# Multiple-column indexes with common prefix

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have a table with the following columns:

```
----------------------
| id | a | b | c | d |
----------------------
```

and I have two composite indexes: `(a, b, c)` and `(a, b, d)`. In this case, the prefix `(a, b)` is shared between both indexes. Does MySQL (or other engine) optimize these indexes' storage and usage? Or the `(a, b)` prefix nodes will be stored (and processed) twice, once for each index?

I'm using mysql 5.6.29, which may influence the analysis.

Comment: @scaisEdge thanks, any reference I can dig into?

Comment: I'm referring to Inno DB  .. and inno DB store index .. in B-tree https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-table-and-index.html