# Indexing in Postgres with common columns

Tags: postgresql, indexing

Suppose I have 4 attributes in my Postgres db a,b,c,d.

I want to create an index on a and b, these are the two options I can go ahead with

1. indexing a and b separately
2. creating index as (c,a) and (c,b)

Will creating index in the 2nd form optimize the performance of db? And how does indexing work in that case?

Comment: Which query do you want to optimise?

Comment: You can never say what indexes a table needs. You can only index *a certain query* of a certain table.

Comment: There is no index `as (c,a) and (c,b)`.  Are you describing 2 separate indexes?

Comment: yes @jjanes those are separate index

Comment: as we know creating indexes slows down write, deletes...so by creating by 2nd options was checking if it would improve the performance of writes in any manner.

Comment: This question is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37057807/multiple-column-indexes-with-common-prefix, the link in the comments is not accessible now, any resource would also be helpful

Comment: @Nitika That question is about mysql, where indices work a bit different than in postgres.

Comment: I have that same question for postgre

Comment: Please include the query you want to optimize. Otherwise the question doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1):

An index can only be efficiently used by a query if a prefix of its columns is applied to the query's `WHERE`-condition. The order of the columns in the `CREATE INDEX`-statement matters. Suppose we have a table

```
CREATE TABLE my_table(
   a INT,
   b INT,
   c INT,
   d INT
);
```

and indexes

```
CREATE INDEX idx_a ON my_table (a);
CREATE INDEX idx_b ON my_table (b);
CREATE INDEX idx_ca ON my_table (c, a);
CREATE INDEX idx_cb ON my_table (c, b);
```

then query

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE a = 42;
```

will only use `idx_a` (while all other indexes won't fit to this query),

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE b = 42;
```

will only use `idx_b` (while all other indexes won't fit to this query),

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE a = 42 and c = 23;
```

will use `idx_ca` (`idx_a` would fit, too, but it has probably less performance),

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE b = 42 and c = 23;
```

will use `idx_cb` (`idx_b` would fit, too, but it has probably less performance) and

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE c = 23;
```

can eather use `idx_ca` or `idx_cb` (the optimizer will decide by statistical information).

So it depends on your queries. If they always include a condition on `c` then `idx_ca` will presumably have better query performance in comparison to `idx_a`.

Of course you shouldn't create indexes on suspicion that actually aren't needed. In `Postgres` you can use `EXPLAIN` ([docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-explain.html)) to see how the optimizer makes use of the indexes you have defined.

Comment: This isn't strictly true. it IS possible for "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE b = 42;" to use an index on (c,b) but (1) it'll only use it if there isn't an index on b directly and (2) it's significantly less efficient than an index in which b is the first element. However, it may still be massively faster than a full table scan - not least because the sheer number of disk blocks involved in reading the index of two columns will be less than that of reading a table with more - this gets more and more true as the tables get wider. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/indexes-multicolumn.html

Answer (score 0):

As already said, it really depends ot the queries on the table.

Postgres can in certain situation use several index for a query.
See this very good answer: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/91269/216879

If it is possible You can create the 4 indexes, and check after some times which of your index are not used by querying the `pg_stat_user_indexes` table.

More litterature about index utilization from the offical documentation:
[https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-bitmap-scans.html#:~:text=Fortunately%2C%20PostgreSQL%20has%20the%20ability,conditions%20across%20several%20index%20scans](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-bitmap-scans.html#:%7E:text=Fortunately%2C%20PostgreSQL%20has%20the%20ability,conditions%20across%20several%20index%20scans).